# Is it possible that two clusters overlap?

Tags: stream, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I want to use Clsutream algorithm (with k-means) to cluster stream data. I want to know that is it possible that the resulting clusters overlap?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition k-means cannot create overlapping clusters, as points are assigned to the closest centroid. There are other clustering methods which can produce overlaping ones, such as fuzzy k-means etc.